# Extending Faker gem locally uninitialized constant Faker::xxx

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, faker

I want to extend the faker gem for rails to also generate other random date (in my case computer game names)

```
#lib/extended_faker.rb
require 'faker'
require 'extended_faker/game'

#lib/extended_faker/game.rb
Module Faker
    class Game < Faker::Base
        class << self
            def name
                fetch('game.name')
            end
        end
    end
end

#config/locals/faker_en.yml
en:
  faker:
    game:
      name: ["a", "b", "c"]

#config/application.rb
...
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
...
```

then when i run it in a rails console i get the following

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.9)
1.9.3p194 :001 > Faker::Game.name
LoadError: Expected /home/enermis/School/Projects/IG/test/lib/extended_faker/game.rb to define Game
    from /home/enermis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:503:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /home/enermis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
    from /home/enermis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
    from /home/enermis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
    from /home/enermis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:514:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /home/enermis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
    from /home/enermis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
    from /home/enermis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
    from (irb):1
    from /home/enermis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /home/enermis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /home/enermis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

When i change the lib/extended_faker/game.rb file to this

```
require 'faker'
require 'extended_faker/game'
include 'extended_faker/item'
include 'extended_faker/team'
```

i get weird behavior in the console

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.9)
1.9.3p194 :001 > Faker::Game.name
 => "b" 
1.9.3p194 :002 > Faker::Game.name
NameError: uninitialized constant Faker::Game
    from (irb):2
    from /home/enermis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /home/enermis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /home/enermis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

The weird thing i don't understand is that the first time i run the generator, i get a valid result, but the second time around i get an error...

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shoud put it in
`lib/faker/game.rb`
starting in the lib directory, rails convention is outermost module name -> in are folder names. Then the actual class/module name is the file name, underscored to the camelcase.
**Another example**

```
module Foo
  module Bar
    class BazParty
      def self.hello
        puts "hello"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

would go in `lib/foo/bar/baz_party.rb`

Comment: Thanks that seems to work indeed..

Is there a way to bypass the rails 'magic' with name matching for this.

Also just out of curiosity i would still like to know why the second approach worked only once.

Comment: you `require File.join(Rails.root, "lib", "extended_faker", "game.rb")` in the file where you are using it I think. I will double check.

Comment: Yes. This works as expected in rails console. I really recommend staying with the convention though. Maybe with `lib/faker/ext/game.rb` then `class Faker::Ext::Game < Faker::Base`  or just calling the folder faker - but I think I get where you're coming from.

Comment: A quick 'style' tip: You can do `require Rails.root.join('lib', 'extended_faker', 'game.rb')`